# Implementing parallel merging in CUDA with shared memory does not enhance performance

Tags: merge, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am trying to implement a parallel merging algorithm in CUDA. The algorithm is designed to be executed in one thread block. Its basic idea is to compute the global rank of each element in two input sequences. Since these two input sequences are sorted, a element's global rank is equal to its index in its original sequence plus its rank in the other sequence which is computed by binary search. I think the best strategy for implementing such algorithm is to load two sequences into shared memory to reduce the global memory read. However, when I compared two version of implementation, one using shared memory and one without using shared memory, I can't see the performance enhancement. I wonder if I am doing something wrong.

Hardware: GeForce GTX 285, Linux x86_64.

The time to merge two sequences of 1024 elements for both implementations is about 0.068672 ms.

```
__global__ void localMerge(int * A, int numA,int * B,int numB,int * C){
    extern __shared__ int  temp[]; // shared memory for A and B; 
    int tx=threadIdx.x;
    int size=blockDim.x;
    int *tempA=temp;
    int *tempB=temp+numA;
    
    int i,j,k,mid;
    //read sequences into shared memory 
    for(i=tx;i<numA;i+=size){
        tempA[i]=A[i];
    }
    for(i=tx;i<numB;i+=size){
        tempB[i]=B[i];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    //compute global rank for elements in sequence A
    for(i=tx;i<numA;i+=size){
        j=0;
        k=numB-1;
        if(tempA[i]<=tempB[0]){
            C[i]=tempA[i];
        }
        else if(tempA[i]>tempB[numB-1]){
            C[i+numB]=tempA[i];
        }
        else{
            while(j<k-1){
                mid=(j+k)/2;
                if(tempB[mid]<tempA[i]){
                    j=mid;
                }
                else{
                    k=mid;
                }
            }
            //printf("i=%d,j=%d,C=%d\n",i,j,tempA[i]);
            C[i+j+1]=tempA[i];
        }
    }   
    //compute global rank for elements in sequence B
    for(i=tx;i<numB;i+=size){
        j=0;
        k=numA-1;
        if(tempB[i]<tempA[0]){
            C[i]=tempB[i];
        }
        else if(tempB[i]>=tempA[numA-1]){
            C[i+numA]=tempB[i];
        }
        else{
            while(j<k-1){
                mid=(j+k)/2;
                if(tempA[mid]<=tempB[i]){
                    j=mid;
                }
                else{
                    k=mid;
                }
            }
            //printf("i=%d,j=%d,C=%d\n",i,j,tempB[i]);
            C[i+j+1]=tempB[i];
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Just so I didn't misunderstand, you are running this kernel with 1 block?

Comment: With so many loops and branching statements I am surprised the cuda version isn't slower. Also when dealing with parallel architectures bitonic merge is the way to go ahead even if the implementation is slower in serial code.

Comment: @talonmies Yes. I execute the kernel with one thread block.

Comment: @xhe8: Running a single block won't let you hide most of the latencies in the architecture, and those will probably give a much larger decrease than any performance improvement from an optimisation like shared memory.

Comment: @talonmies Actually I do implement a parallel merging algorithm that partitions long input sequences into many smaller sub-sequences, and a block of threads execute the above algorithm to merge each pair of sub-sequence. The reason why I posted this question is that I want to know why the implementation with shared memory does not perform better than that without shared memory.

Comment: @talonmies Even though I ran the parallel merging program with multiple thread blocks, the performance for both implementation are pretty much the same. For example, the time for merging two sequences of 500000 elements is about 1.536896 ms.

Answer (score 5):

You may have more luck with applying the "[merge path](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/%7Eogreen3/_docs/GPU%20Merge%20Path%20-%20A%20GPU%20Merging%20Algorithm.pdf)" algorithm than by relying on a collection of parallel fine-grained binary searches through both input lists in `__shared__` memory. Using `__shared__` memory for this problem is less important because what reuse exists in this algorithm can be captured pretty well by the cache.

With this merge algorithm, the idea is that each thread of the CTA is responsible for producing `k` outputs in the merged result. This has the nice property that each thread's work is roughly uniform, and the binary searching involved is fairly coarse grained.

Thread `i` searches both input lists *at once* to find the position in each list of the `k*i`th output element. The job then is simple: each thread serially merges `k` items from the input lists and copies them to location `k*i` in the output.

You can refer to [Thrust's implementation](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/cuda-5.5/thrust/system/cuda/detail/merge.inl#L79) for the details.